# Pushed on detached head, not showing my push or commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

**Hey there,**

I had some uncommitted files on my local codes, At a situation when i need to pull, i stash my changes and files then i pull and change everything and push continuously some commits!
I figured out i need those files i stashed! So i checked-out on that commit i stashed my changes, So i stashed pop and my changes appeared on So i commit those changes and push But it errors its pushing on detached head so i accept in it pushed! 
But in my remote there isn't that commit i pushed!
WTF i must do to bring back my changes?!
Someone says i commit on Detached Head  on local, how can i find it?!

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution:

I go to .git/logs/ and nano HEAD and find my commit and checkout on that commit!